# Classifying Symbolic Values and Symbolic Variables within a Symbolic Array

Tags: matlab, symbols, symbolic-math

I have a vector of six values (but it can be infinitely long) of type "sym". In this case the vector has numbers and variables (all class sym).

```
a=[0.6 ; x_1; 0; 0; x_2; 0]
```

I want to write an algorithm that can tell if a(1)=number, a(1)=zero or, a(1)=variable.

But if `x_1` and `x_2` are symbolic variables then the array `a` and all of its elements are automatically symbolic, i.e., `class(a(1))` will return `'sym'` (from @horchler).

Comment: So why don't you do it if *you* want to write it? Please [edit] the question with what you tried in a [mcve], and explain clearly what the problem is with that code.Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Adriaan I'm asking a question I don't know the answer to, probably someone has a simple solution to it. I know its not a code writing service. But I don't know the function to write if I do:  if a(1)=='a symbol' and differentiate x_2 from 0.6 for example since both will be class sym.

Comment: @SardarUsama: I'd say that using regular expressions for this would be the "bad way."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time helping out :)

Comment: Regular expressions are slow in Matlab and symbolic variables/expressions are a class with their own methods that are the preferred/safe way to work with them. Converting between symbolic math and strings is strongly discouraged by The MathWorks (see note atop many of the symbolic math doc pages, e.g., [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html)).

Comment: Thanks @horchler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `x_1` and `x_2` are symbolic variables then the array `a` and all of its elements are automatically symbolic, i.e., `class(a(1))` will return `'sym'`. It looks like you want to determine if an element is a symbolic value or a symbolic expression (made up of one or more symbolic variables). You can use [`symvar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/symvar.html) for this. You'll need to iterate through your array with a `for` loop to check each element, for example:

```
syms x_1 x_2;
a = [0.6; x_1; 0; 0; x_2; 0];

for ai = vpa(a(:).')
    if isempty(symvar(ai))
        if ai == 0
            disp('Zero value');
        else
            disp('Non-zero value');
        end
    else
        disp('Symbolic expression or function');
    end
end
```

The `vpa` function is used to evaluate any expressions in `a` that might simplify to a numeric value. You can remove the `vpa` if you know what your input array looks like. You can use `double` to convert symbolic values to floating-point if desired.

Comment: Thanks @horchler, the difference with symbolic value and expression is what I really didn't understand. This solves my doubt. Thanks for your time and help.